# Joining multiple tables to show last order date by customer, by product and by vendor

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to solve the following query, there's a few additional parameters, but these are the main attributes required:

**Provide the product details, which vendors supply these products, and what was the last date these products were ordered by customers.**

I have my original query below which gets me 90% of the way. I just can't seem to figure out how to display the last order date by customer per individual product. I've tried embedding **(select max(o.OrderDate) from orders as o)** into my select statement, but it only displays the latest order date of all of the products, not the individual per product last order date (e.g., all dates listed are 01/01/2020 when I know other products' last order date was before this date).

Apologies, I do not have enough rep to post pictures in line with text, therefore I have attached pictures of table structure and my query.

[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abf7j.png)
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCzu7.png)

Query:

```
select distinct p.ProductNumber, p.ProductName, p.RetailPrice, p.QuantityOnHand, v.VendName, 
(select max(o.OrderDate)
from orders as o)
as LastOrderDateByCust
from ((((orders as o
inner join order_details as od
on od.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber)
inner join products as p
on p.ProductNumber = od.ProductNumber)
inner join product_vendors as pv
on p.ProductNumber = pv.ProductNumber)
inner join vendors as v
on pv.VendorID = v.VendorID)
where p.QuantityOnHand < '10'
order by LastOrderDateByCust DESC;`
```

Comment: Please post your query as a text and not as an image, and kindly provide your table structure including the delete and insert query.

Comment: Please read **[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).**

Comment: @TheCoolCat fixed I hope, I'm not sure how I can post a whole table structure in text format so I posted a picture. I hope that is ok

Comment: @The Cool Cat see above

Answer (score 0):

figured it out on my own I believe:

```
select distinct p.ProductNumber, p.ProductName, c.CategoryDescription, p.RetailPrice, pv.WholesalePrice, p.QuantityOnHand, v.VendName, pv.DaysToDeliver, (select max(o.OrderDate)
from orders as o
inner join order_details as od
on o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber
where od.ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber)
as LastOrderDateByCust
from (((((orders as o
inner join order_details as od
on o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber)
inner join products as p
on p.ProductNumber = od.ProductNumber)
inner join product_vendors as pv
on p.ProductNumber = pv.ProductNumber)
inner join vendors as v
on pv.VendorID = v.VendorID)
inner join categories as c
on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID)
where od.ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber and p.QuantityOnHand < '10'
order by p.ProductNumber;`
```